# Can I use template specialization or type coercion here?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++14, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have an existing template for mapping slow functions to collections (in the style of a clojure function of the same name) that I want to speed up with "move semantics" in the flavor of this helpful blog post not by me: http://blog.knatten.org/2012/11/02/efficient-pure-functional-programming-in-c-using-move-semantics/

This old code I wrote works well for me:

```
template <typename function,
      template <typename...> class collection,
      typename in_type,
      typename... types,
      typename out_type = 
        typename std::result_of<function(in_type)>::type>
static collection<out_type> pmap(
  const function& f, const collection<in_type, types...>& c)  {
  collection<out_type> result;
  if(!c.empty())  {
    result = collection<out_type>(c.size());   
    __gnu_parallel::transform(c.cbegin(),c.cend(),result.begin(),f);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Since I'm willing to commit to throwing away the input collection, I should be able to speed this up in the case in which the in_type is the same as the out_type by writing over c instead of allocating a whole new collection. I tried a template specialization but the compiler couldn't choose in the special case, and I couldn't come up with a fix. Here is my attempt at some sleight of hand:

```
template <typename function,
      template <typename...> class collection,
      typename in_type,
      typename... types,
      typename out_type = 
        typename std::result_of<function(in_type)>::type>
static collection<out_type> pmap(
  const function& f, const collection<in_type, types...>&& c)  {
  collection<out_type> result;
  if(!c.empty())  {
    if(typeid(in_type)==typeid(out_type))  {
      __gnu_parallel::transform(c.begin(),c.end(),c.begin(),f);
      result = c;
    }
    else  {
      result = collection<out_type>(c.size());
      __gnu_parallel::transform(c.cbegin(),c.cend(),result.begin(),f);
    }
  }
  return std::move(result);
}
```

I guess there is some hack that would make the compiler accept result=c (even though it shouldn't care anyway because of the surrounding if-statement), but casting like that makes me feel uneasy.  Any suggestions for how to fix this or add a specialization template for the write-over case?

Answer (score 2):

`typeid` is a runtime construct, so you are trying to select behaviour at runtime rather than compile-time.

You could write two overloads and select the right one using `std::enable_if`:

```
template <typename function,
      template <typename...> class collection,
      typename in_type,
      typename... types,
      typename out_type = 
        typename std::result_of<function(in_type)>::type,
      typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<in_type, out_type>::value>::type* = nullptr>
static collection<out_type> pmap(
  const function& f, collection<in_type, types...>&& c)  {
  collection<out_type> result;
  result.reserve(c.size());
  __gnu_parallel::transform(c.cbegin(),c.cend(),std::back_inserter(result),f);


  return result;
}

template <typename function,
      template <typename...> class collection,
      typename in_type,
      typename... types,
      typename out_type = 
        typename std::result_of<function(in_type)>::type,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<in_type, out_type>::value>::type* = nullptr>
static collection<out_type,types...> pmap(
  const function& f, collection<in_type, types...>&& c)  {
  __gnu_parallel::transform(c.begin(),c.end(),c.begin(),f);

  return std::move(c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your enable_if example got me going. I'm not sure you can do this without move semantics... it appears you are writing to a const & in your second part, which I have never tried.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you'll need to take a non-const reference (or even an rvalue reference) if you want to modify `c`.

Comment: You also miss `types...` for the return type. You may also return by reference.